# Is it possible to simulate a shared folder without changing the name of the computer?

Tags: directory, shared, simulate

I need run a local demo of a program that have a hardcoded path to a .mbd database in the format:

```
\\\ComputerName\SharedFolder\db.mbd
```

I can't change the name of the local machine because it is needed for logging purposes.

So is there a way to simulate a shared folder without changing the name of the computer?

Comment: This belongs on serverfault.com, but I'd suggest your best option is to consider remapping "ComputerName" in your hosts file to point to your local computer. Assuming you can't, say, get rid of the hard coded path, which is evil.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the right place for the question, did not know it. Your suggest is the best option, but I don't have the code source :-S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was install a virtual machine, set the same computer name and place the mdb file in the same path